# Making a funnel plot for a diagnostic network meta analysis

Tags: r, statistics, diagnostics

When I am trying to perform a funnel plot using the "netmeta" package in r. However, when i try to run the code, it returns a NULL.

```
#sensitivity OR

p1 <- pairwise(type, event = TP, TP+FN, studlab = total$studynames,
               data = total, sm = "OR", allstudies = TRUE)           
p1
nb1 <- netmetabin(p1, method = "MH", ref = "A")
netleague(nb1, digits = 3)
netrank(nb1)
nb1
plot(netrank(nb1))
forest(nb1)
```

Forest plot seems to work and calculating SUCRA scores (netrank) seems to work too (meaning the objects are created correctly). When I use the exact same code for the example databases it does work (not binary data). Is it possible that this is due to the fact that my object is "netmetabin" instead of "netmeta"? If so, what is the alternative to making a funnel plot for binary data for a diagnostic network meta-analysis?

thanks in advance.

Comment: is there a package like this in python? i am trying to do meta analysis for diagnostic studies in python

Comment: R (and Rstudio) are very useful for (diagnostic) meta-analysis (and ofcourse other statistical endeavours). It is quite similar to python so I do recommend using R instead of python since it has much more statistical packages. However, I did encounter a package for python in this [link](https://pypi.org/project/PythonMeta/).